# What is the most efficient method of landing for space capsules returning to earth?

Tags: apollo-program, soyuz-spacecraft, dragon-v2, orion-spacecraft, cst-100

I have read that the Russians don't land on water because they don't have access to a large warm-water coastline like the US. US has large swaths of land and water and most US capsules (Apollo, Dragon, Orion) chose water, which suggests water is the superior method. But then again Starliner (something in same generation as Dragon) chose land. Also on land-based methods is there significant advantages/disadvantages between using air bags like Starliner or retro-rockets like New Shepard/Soyuz.

Comment: What is your metric for "efficient"? Lowest cost to retrieve? Least fuel consumed? Lowest cost to refurbish for reuse?

Comment: Sometimes it's not about efficiency but other requirements. Returning to land requires an engine & fuel. These add mass to the vehicle & present a safety issue - ensuring the fuel does not ignite explode on re-entry. Not having an engine & fuel allows for more payload that can be used in Space or more consumables for an extended mission in Space. It can also come down to the priorities for mission or program.

Comment: @HABO I guess Lowest cost per mission, while other things being broadly equal. As Fred said landing with rockets require engines and fuel and may be splashdown requires extra stuff for buoyancy and recovery vessels, and replace some parts that come in contact with salt water when reusing capsule, air bags r also going to occupy some space

Comment: For small (~1m sphere) unmanned capsules, ***caught in midair*** by an airplane has also been used ([CORONA](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/corona-film-return-capsule/nasm_A19950118000) and [successors](https://www.nro.gov/History-and-Studies/Center-for-the-Study-of-National-Reconnaissance/The-CORONA-Program/Fact-Sheet/)).